# i just created an xml in drawable to call different image. but it display only first two image in three tab. please guide me where i went wrong

Tags: android-actionbar-tabs

i just created 3 tabs in action bar.and instead of giving text am assigning image for each tab. and trying to call red color image for all tabs when it is not selected.while pressing any button that particular button should call green color image.
        private static final int[] tabs = { R.drawable.actionbar_tab,
            R.drawable.actionbar_tabmyorder, R.drawable.action_tabtracker };

and in on tabselect method i am passing following comment

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    LinearLayout tabLayout = (LinearLayout) tab.getCustomView();

    tabLayout.setBackgroundResource(tabs[tab.getPosition()]);
    tab.setCustomView(tabLayout);
```

### R.drawable.action_tabtracker code as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tracker_orange" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tracker_orange" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tracker_green" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tracker_orange" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tracker_green" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tracker_orange" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tracker_green" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

##